# How to use Git to migrate SVN repository

Tags: git, migration, repository, git-svn

Somebody is planning to move the subversion repository I work on (8000+ commits).

Is there a way to use git-svn to replay the last, say, 20 commits from the old location once the migration is finished?

(not only my own commits, but also other team members)

Bonus question: How do I add multiple svn repositories to my git local copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that [git svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) is the right tool for that job. The documentation contains the statement when discussing the *--commit-url* option:

> Commit to this SVN URL (the full path). This is intended to allow existing git svn repositories created with one transport method (e.g. svn:// or http:// for anonymous read) to be reused if a user is later given access to an alternate transport method (e.g. svn+ssh:// or https://) for commit.
>
> Using this option for any other purpose (don't ask) is very strongly discouraged.

I'm not sure precisely what that warning applies to, but it *may* apply to the "bridge" situation you are describing. If you decide to proceed with git-svn, you may be wise to proceed with caution.

Comment: I'm not really doing anything to proceed with git-svn. (just using it locally). However, I would think, the strategy for replaying commits via git-svn could eliminate a no-commit period for team members. With your tip on modifying the --commit-url, each team member could individually use git to commit locally and wait for the new repos to come up.